# Identifying An Encryption Algorithm

Tags: encryption

First off, I would like to ask if any of you know of an encryption algorithm that uses a key to encrypt the data, but no key to decrypt the data. This seems highly unlikely, if not impossible to me, so sorry if it's a stupid question.

My final question is, say you have access to the plain text data before it is encrypted, the key used to encrypt the plain text data, and the resulting encrypted data, would figuring out which algorithm used to encrypt the data be feasible?

Comment: Why encrypt with a key if anyone can decrypt it without? Can't you just send the plaintext over, then? If you just want to scramble your data, use ROT13...

Comment: ...or are you looking for cryptographic signatures?

Comment: good point, there may be confusion of encryption and signatures here. or, the OP may be thinking of a hash algorithm.

Answer (score 9):

> First off, I would like to ask
>   if any of you know of an encryption
>   algorithm that uses a key to encrypt
>   the data, but no key to decrypt the
>   data.

No. There are algorithms that use a different key to decrypt than to encrypt, but a keyless method would rely on secrecy of the algorithm, generally regarded as a poor idea.

> My final question is, say you have
>   access to the plain text data before
>   it is encrypted, the key used to
>   encrypt the plain text data, and the
>   resulting encrypted data, would
>   figuring out which algorithm used to
>   encrypt the data be feasible?

Most likely yes, especially given the key. A good crypto algorithm relies on the secrecy of the key, and the key alone. See [kerckhoff's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27_principle).

Also if a common algorithm is used it would be a simple matter of trial and error, and besides cryptotext often is accompanied by metadata which tells you algorithm details.

*edit: as per comments, you may be thinking of [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) (which requires a secret only on the sender side), a [hash algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (which requires no key but isn't encryption), or a [zero-knowledge proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_knowledge_proof) (which can prove knowledge of a secret without revealing it).*

Answer (score 5):

Abstractly, we can think of the encryption system this way:

```
               -------------------
plaintext ---> | algorithm & key | ---> ciphertext
               -------------------
```

The system *must* guarantee the following:

***decrypt***(***encrypt***(plaintext, algorithm, key), algorithm, key) = plaintext

> First off, I would like to ask
>   if any of you know of an encryption
>   algorithm that uses a key to encrypt
>   the data, but no key to decrypt the
>   data.

Yes, in such a system the key is redundant; all the "secrecy" lies in the algorithm.

> My final question
>   is, say you have access to the plain
>   text data before it is encrypted, the
>   key used to encrypt the plain text
>   data, and the resulting encrypted
>   data, would figuring out which
>   algorithm used to encrypt the data be
>   feasible?

In practice, you'll probably have a small space of algorithms, so a simple brute-force search is feasible. However, there may be more than one algorithm that fits the given information. Consider the following example:

We define the following encryption and decryption operations, where plaintext, ciphertext, algorithm, and key are real numbers (assume algorithm is nonzero):

***encrypt***(plaintext, algorithm, key) = algorithm x (plaintext + key) = ciphertext

***decrypt***(ciphertext, algorithm, key) = ciphertext/algorithm - key = plaintext

Now, suppose that plaintext + key = 0. We have ciphertext = 0 for any choice of algorithm. Hence, we cannot deduce the algorithm used.

Answer (score 1):

> First off, I would like to ask if any of you know of an encryption algorithm that uses a key to encrypt the data, but no key to decrypt the data.

What are you getting at?  It's trivial to come up with a pair of functions that fits the letter of the specification, but without knowing the intent it's hard to give a more helpful answer.

> say you have access to the plain text data before it is encrypted, the key used to encrypt the plain text data, and the resulting encrypted data, would figuring out which algorithm used to encrypt the data be feasible?

If the algorithm is any good the output will be indistinguishable from random noise, so there is no analytic solution to this.  As a practical matter, there are only so many trusted algorithms in wide use.  Trying each one in turn would be quick, but would be complicated by the fact that an implementation has some freedom with regard to things like byte order (little-endian vs big-endian), key derivation (if you had a pass-phrase instead of the actual cryptographic key itself), encryption modes and padding.

As frankodwyer points out, this situation is not part of usual threat models.  This would work in your favor, as it makes it more likely that the algorithm is a well-known one.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do without a known key in the decoder would be to add a bit of obscurity. For example, if the first step of the decode algorythm is to strip out everything except for every tenth character, then your encode key may be used to seed some random garbage for nine out of every ten characters. Thus, with different keys you could achieve different encoded results which would be decoded to the same message, with no key necessary for the decoder.

However, this does not add much real security and should not be solely relied on to protect crucial data. I'm just thinking of a case where it would be possible to do so yes I suppose it could - if you were just trying to prove a point or add one more level of security.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is such an algorithm that would use a key to encrypt, but not to decrypt.  (Silly answers like a 26 character [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) aside...)

To your second question, yes; it just depends on how much time you're willing to spend on it.  In theoretical cryptography it is assumed that the algorithm can always be determined.  Whether that be through theft of the algorithm or a physical machine, or as in your case having a plain text and cipher text pair.